# WSO2 ISO8583 Initiate and Maintain Connection with Server

Tags: wso2, esb, iso8583, wso2-esb

We've configured WSO2 using the below ISO8583 endpoint to receive messages and communicate with a RESTful API.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+ISO8583+Inbound+Operations

The provider we're integrating with are expecting that we will initiate the connection with their server on the 5000 port, and only then will they begin sending transactions to us. I'm primarily experienced with RESTful APIs so I'm not familiar with WSO2 and opening and maintaining a socket connection. How do I need to configure WSO2 to create and maintain the connection with the host / port from which we expect all transaction to then originate?

I assume this will be via the ISO8583 connector however need guidance.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+ISO8583+Connector+Operation

Answer (score 0):

Could you please elaborate more on your requirements. While reading the description, I do not think that you have a requirement to consume  ISO8583 standard messages. Please use this connector only if you are consuming ISO8583 standard messages.

You can refer to the documentation on the inbound endpoint in document [1] to further clarification regarding the listening inbound endpoint, in which you can define a host and a port. Please elaborate more on the type of messages that need to be consumed how to interact with the backend to provide with a more infomative answer

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/WSO2+EI+Inbound+Endpoints